# Iterator Pattern pass through parameter

Tags: c#, design-patterns

How can I pass through parameter a variable that is my `Iterator` ?

```
protected void LeXMLNode(FileUpload fupArquivo)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(fupArquivo.FileContent);

            XmlNodeList ndo = doc.SelectNodes("*");

            var it = ndo.GetEnumerator();
            using (it as IDisposable)
            while (it.MoveNext())
            {                
                //// Pass the variable it as parameter
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The problem is the assignature of the parameter in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.Current` property:

```
using (var it = ndo.GetEnumerator())
    while (it.MoveNext())
    {                
        //// Pass the variable it as parameter
        SomeFunction(it.Current);
    }
```

Comment: and if I want to pass the whole "it" variable ?

Comment: Don't. That would be a poor design choice. But if you think you really must, your function must be written to accept an IEnumerator (or an IEnumerator<someGenericOrSpecificType>) as an argument.

Comment: Well, so if you tell that this is a poor desgin choice, I belive. and how would be the assignature of a method that receive `it.Current` ?

Comment: Note that the enumerator implementations are often value types, so you may also need to pass by ref (as otherwise MoveNext will only mutate the copy of the enumerator rather than the original enumerator.)  In general, it's a bad idea to pass around the enumerator.

Comment: @DanBryant understood, I had no idea of that. But how would be the assignature of a method that receives `it.Current` ?